# custom filters 10 $digest iterations reached?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 10 select list with more than 10 options per each , and I have this error due to the maximum number of digest loop that angular set to 10 ,

on these select lists I apply these two custom filters and causing the error :

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

```
app.filter('sortFilter', function() {
    return function(items) {
        items.sort(function (item1, item2) {
          return (item1.order > item2.order ? 1 : -1);
        });
        return items;
    };
});


app.filter('removeDuplicationFilter', function() {
    return function(items, thisOption) {
        var options=[];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
             if ( item.order == 0 ) {
                options.push(item);
            } else if (thisOption == item.name) {
                options.push(item);
            }
        });
        return options;
    };
});

<div ng-repeat="field in fields|sortFilter" ng-if="filterField.order">
 <select ng-model="field.name" ng-options="item.name as item.label for item in fields | removeDuplicationFilter:field.name"></select>
</div>
```

Please advice , Thanks

UPDATE:
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vnb8jL91/2/)

Comment: Did you try the two filters separately? Does one cause the problem or only the combination? Please try to narrow down the problem as far as possible.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vnb8jL91/1/ Please update the fiddle to illustrate your problem

Comment: @lex82 i have updated the fiddle with the issue http://jsfiddle.net/vnb8jL91/2/  which turned out to be the combination of ng-repeat with the filter

Comment: I still don't see an error in your fiddle

Comment: it is in the console if you do inspect element , doesn't affect the functionality here @lex82

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. For me it seems everything is working fine.

Comment: i am using chrome , what about you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91833/discussion-between-lex82-and-sisimh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `sortFilter` modifies the value its supposed to filter, i.e., it changes the model. This in turn triggers another digest cycle and sorting happens again. You can easily fix it by returning a sorted copy of the array like this:

```
myApp.filter('sortFilter', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var result = items.concat([]); // copies the array
        result.sort(function (item1, item2) {
          return (item1.order > item2.order ? 1 : -1);
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```